# Casting to a different type each loop iteration

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to cast items in a loop into a different type each iteration. Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++)
  newArr.push({
    date:arrA[i].subArr[j].myDate, 
    points+i:arrA[i].subArr[j].myPoints,
    league+i:arrA[i].subArr[j].myLeague
  });
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Huh, where are you casting in that example? And what does not work with that code?

Comment: what is `arrA`? what is `subArr`? what is `myPoints`? what is `myLeague`? you can't expect us to provide guidance with such a small amount of information.

Comment: You may want to use the edit function below the post to revise the question, after you clarify in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to create an object and alter the properties afterwards before adding it to the array?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        var tmp = {};
        tmp['date'] = arrA[i].subArr[j].myDate;
        tmp['points'+i] = arrA[i].subArr[j].myPoints;
        tmp['league'+i] = arrA[i].subArr[j].myLeague;
        newArr.push(tmp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that approach makes much sense. You'd be better off just having a completely separate "index" property for each object you're creating.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    newArr.push({
      index: i,
      date: arrA[i].subArr[j].myDate, 
      points: arrA[i].subArr[j].myPoints,
      league: arrA[i].subArr[j].myLeague
    });
```

That way all your objects look alike, with an "index" property in the range of 0 to 99 for each one.

Comment: I need to get all the data into a single array to display in a chart, and each line on the chart requires a unique 'value' identifier. Sadly I can't think of a way to do that using an index.

Comment: It's not clear what "value identifier" means; what charting package are we talking about here?

Comment: amcharts. As far as I can tell the only way to display multiple lines is by having an array of this format:                     chartData.push({
                        date: newDate,
                        visits: visits,
                        hits: hits,
                        views: views
                    });
(taken from their example, and after reading their forums).
then each line requires a line as follows:
graph1.valueField = "visits";
graph2.valueField = "hits";

Comment: OK well reading their documentation it sure doesn't seem that way to me, but if you can get it to work then that's great I guess :-)

Comment: By 'doesnt seem that way to you' do you mean that there's a better way to go about it?

Comment: No, what I mean is that the docs for amcharts suggests to me that the objects should look different than what you're setting up. However I don't know exactly which of their chart types you're using so I could be wrong.

Comment: I take it you're referring to the 'stock charts' which are the ones they say support multiple data sets. I don't think they suit my needs, though I'll have a second look. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Property names in [object initializers](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5) may not be arbitrary expressions, so this is invalid syntax:

```
newArr.push({
    "points" + i: arrA[i].subArr[j].myPoints
});
```

However, you can use arbitrary expressions in subscripts:

```
var tmp = {};
tmp["points" + i] = arrA[i].subArr[j].myPoints;
...
newArr.push(tmp);
```